# Regular expression for staff member

Tags: regex

I am trying to get a regular expression that will match on any of the following strings:

```
Sales Director:
Managing Director:
Sales Manager:
General Manager - Power:
Finance Director:
Procurement Manager:
Director:
Director:
Managing Director:
Finance Director:
Sales Director:
Managing Director:
Sales Manager:
Finance Director:
Procurement Manager:
```

But not on:

```
print directories and guides
defence Industry Directory
```

so far I have:

```
/(manager|director)/i
```

But this is obviously going to match on directories, directory etc.

I know the $ sign signifies the end of a word but I cannot get the right syntax.

Should I be using word boundaries like `\b`?

I also DO NOT want to pull back whole sentences with manager or director in the sentence.  I think I want a maximum of 2 words where manager or directory is the first or second word.  Is this possible?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: T<o which programming language are you interested?

Comment: There are about a thousand regex systems in the wild, some of which do not match on "directories" because they do not assume by default that you want a substring match. You should be more precise in what context this question is placed.

Comment: *I think I want a maximum of 2 words* "General Manager - Power" is three words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I be using word boundaries like \b?

Yes, you need word boundaries here:

```
/\b(manager|director)\b/i
```

---

> I think I want a maximum of 2 words where manager or director is the first or second word. Is this possible?

Yes, you *can* do this with a single regular expression ([rubular](http://rubular.com/r/DctaR9oo4R)):

```
/^(?:\w+ +)?(manager|director)\b/i
```

This searches for either:

- the word manager or director at the beginning of the line or
- one word, one or more spaces, then the word manager or director

Comment: @dagda: It makes the group non-capturing. You can remove the `?:` and see how it affects the results (see the part where it says "match captures" underneath the match results).

Answer (score 0):

Different "flavours" of regex have different capabilities, so you should tag your question with the technology in which you are working.

If your regex engine supports negative lookahead (a "zero-width assertion"), you can use
`director(?![yi])` to exclude instances of `director` that are followed by a `y` or `i`.

Really, a word boundary is probably just fine.